# Warning popup on excel files that are exported by ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I noticed that this warning message always pops up every time I open the excel file exported by my web app

> filename.xls, is in a different format
>   than specified by the file extension.
>   Verify that the file is not
>   corrupted.....

Here's the code used:

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Single_Raw.xls"));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                Table tb = new Table();
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();


                tr.Cells.Add((rawRow((lblPOR1.Text.Substring(0, 4)), (lblPOR1.Text.Substring(5, 3)), (lblPOR1.Text.Substring(9, 3)), lblPNL.Text.ToString())));

                TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                cell3.Text = "&nbsp;";

                TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
                tr2.Cells.Add((rawRow((lblPOR2.Text.Substring(0, 4)), (lblPOR2.Text.Substring(5, 3)), (lblPOR2.Text.Substring(9, 3)), lblPNL.Text.ToString())));




                tb.Rows.Add(tr);
                tb.Rows.Add(tr2);

                tb.RenderControl(htw);

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it needs a different content type:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem, which was solved by leaving the extension out of the filename. So "Single_Raw.xls" would be "Single_Raw".

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what mime-type your environment thinks an excel-file should have; according to this overview of [mime types](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml), there are at least these common:

- application/excel
- application/vnd.ms-excel
- application/x-excel
- application/x-msexcel

There should be a tool or (config) file to check for configured and possibly add new mime-types in your environment, so at least you can get rid of the warning yourself.